# Seaside calling a component inside javascript

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

I have a seaside application with a master-detail page. The master page has a table that consists of a list of `tr` records. When the user clicks a particular `tr` element, I want to call a detail component, which'll show the individual record's data.

Since I cannot make a `tr` element with `callback` or have it contain an anchor with a callback, I want the `tr`'s `onClick` property to have some JavaScript which'll `call: subcomponent` . When I tried this, I got an error saying `call: can only be used in callbacks and tasks`.

Using ajax is a workaround, however it breaks the back button.

Edit:

More generally, I'd like to know how to set callback like behaviour for various JavaScript events.

Comment: why can't your TR contain an anchor?

Comment: Html doesn't allow an entire table row to have a single anchor, only `td`s are allowed to contain anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you cannot render a component in a tr element, but you could add some anchor or other element in one of its td children.

For my project I did roughly the following: I added an anchor to each row with a special css class, e.g. '.dblclick-action'. This anchor has a normal Seaside callback.

Then I bound a dblclick handler to the tr element that does something like document.location=$(this).find('.dblclick.ction').get(0).href;

I am not close to a Smalltalk image now to give you source code, but I hope you get the idea: you don't use Ajax to click the link in that particular row, but instead have the browser navigate to the callback that is associated to the link in that row. You could say you use the tr.'s dblclick handler to click the link and then let the normal Seaside stuff do its work. No magic there. You can find a little bit more info [here](http://joachimtuchel.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/clicking-a-link-in-javascript-with-seaside/).

If you don't want the anchor to be visible you may want to experiment with making the anchor invisible (display: none) or the like.

If you are a bit more experiment friendly, you can also try saving a callback on the server and render its url with callback id as an attribute of the tr element and use the dblclick handler to follow the link from that attribute you extract the value of an attribute in query using attr().

Comment: This approach worked for me. Thanks. Additionally, I set the anchors to have no text-decoration and changed it's font so that it wouldn't look like an anchor.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to answer your initial question: you cannot issue a call: from javascript. But you can use the document.location trick to re/misuse an existing link to a callback on the page using the technique I described in my first answer.